# MATLAB R2016a Uninstall

Tags: matlab

I'm unable to uninstall MATLAB;

```
sandeep@sandeep-VPCEH28FN:~$ sudo rm /var/tmp/lm_TMW*
[sudo] password for sandeep: 
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/lm_TMW*': No such file or directory
sandeep@sandeep-VPCEH28FN:~$ sudo apt-get purge matlab
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
sandeep@sandeep-VPCEH28FN:~$ sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
sandeep@sandeep-VPCEH28FN:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove Matlab through an `apt-get` operation, just as you did not install it through an `apt-get` operation. You need to uninstall it manually.

If you followed the official instructions to installing it, then you are the owner, as you can see in the image below (`Owner` tab):

[image]

In consequence, you just need to delete that folder (in your case, 2016a). If you are not the owner, then you need to remove using `sudo`, as it follows:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/MATLAB/
```

You also have a configuration file in your home folder (`~/`), under the name of `./matlab`. If you want to delete this too (you might not do this if you are going to reinstall, for example), enable hidden files in your file explorer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to be able to see it.

Finally, remove any symbolic link that might exist in the `/usr/local/bin` folder. In my case I just have these two but check for the 2016a version:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mex
```

(run with `sudo` if you are not the owner).

**EDIT**: There might be other files related to your Matlab installation (as suggested [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102428-how-do-i-uninstall-matlab-products-on-a-unix-or-linux-machine?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com&nocookie=true)). For example, you might have some files in `/var/tmp/`, which you can remove too. (I do not have them, but it depends on the packages you have).

Comment: There are a couple of additional files that you didn't cover (see https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102428-how-do-i-uninstall-matlab-products-on-a-unix-or-linux-machine) but your answer is largely spot-on.

Comment: Thanks. Strangely, I do not have those! :o Should I? panic panic...

Comment: Nah, those files you didn't cover depend on the toolboxes being installed, so not everyone will have them. :P

Comment: Mmm, that post seems to be very generic. I think I have the generic toolboxes. Anyway, I will update the answer.

Comment: Also, MATLAB for some reason puts the crash dumps in `~` itself, so that's also something you can mention if you want.

Comment: Please feel free to edit. I don't have any such file! It seems I'm not such a hardcore user.